# nginx - Filelisting encoding messed up

Tags: windows, nginx, special-characters

I'm using nginx 1.17.8 on Windows 10. In the config I have set `autoindex on`, which works fine. But then some files with special characters are wrongly encoded / messed up:
The auto generated link for `Prüfstand.jpg` is `Pr%FCfstand.jpg`, but I needs it to be `Pr%C3%BCfstand.jpg`.

Edit 1: As suggested by a user below you need to set charset-settings. I've tried those settings (which don't work):

```
include            win-utf;
source_charset     windows-1251;
charset            utf-8;
override_charset   on;
```

Edit 2:
Now I'm currently stuck with those settings, which I think should work correct:

```
charset_map  windows-1251  utf-8 {
    FC  C3BC ; # ü      
}
charset_types    *;
source_charset   windows-1251;
charset          utf-8;
override_charset on;
```

Those settings are effecting the encoding. If I comment out `FC  C3BC ;`, the ü is not converted corretly. As you can see the settings are active. But still the problem is, that the autogenerated link is wrong (`Pr%FCfstand.jpg`). I've checked the response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.17.8
Date: Mon, 02 Mar 2020 19:15:18 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
```

They are fine aswell (`charset=utf-8`). Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?
I've also found this related question: [autoindex list UTF-8 charset in Nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/966901/autoindex-list-utf-8-charset-in-nginx) which seems similiar. But the author did not provide enough information for me to be sure it's the same issue.

Comment: [Text-Encoding, Codepage, Charset on Torsten-Horn.de](https://www.torsten-horn.de/techdocs/encoding.htm) shows that CP1252/ISO 8859-1/15 would encode ü as FC. So it's not wrong as your underlying filesystem/windows is probably using that. Check [How to enable correct charset HTTP-header in NGINX](https://serverfault.com/questions/312177/how-to-enable-correct-charset-http-header-in-nginx) on ServerFault.

Comment: Thanks for the suggest. I've tried those, but it doesn't work well. I guess I'm not using the right combination of those settings. (I've updated my question)

Comment: Did you check what header that page is sent with? Did you try to actively set a non utf-8 codepage as the charset? What does happen if you click the link? It might be worth it to file it as a bug as nginx for windows is considered to be [in beta](http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html). Some report it works fine running it using cygwin (which isn't that surprising) you might also be able to run it using WSL. Have you considered those options?

Comment: Is autoindex returning links that do not work?

Comment: @Seth I've added a new edit. And regarding your other questions: When I click the link, the link opens and the file is not found (because the auto-generated link is wrong). Maybe it's a bug, yes. I will wait for an answer or a comment. I won't use cygwin, because I want it to work without another software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [autoindex module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html) of nginx windows build (1.17.8) doesn't support any option to give it a encoding. As such it will use whatever is the base of the data it's reading or be influenced by charset settings. What you're facing is likely a bug in that module.

On windows this is typically data with an encoding of particualar codepage that is region depended. In this case [Windows-1251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) seems to be used by nginx. Some other encodings that might be relevant are ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-15, [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) or UTF-16.

You've pointed out that the encoding of ü as `FC` is wrong multiple times but that isn't actually the case. Even within [unicode](https://unicode-table.com/en/00FC/) it should be FC. It just so happens that within UTF-8 it is `C3 BC`. For some more character comparisons have a look at [torsten-horn.de: Text-Encoding, Codepage, Charset](https://www.torsten-horn.de/techdocs/encoding.htm). What you haven't included in your posting is an error message that shows up in the error log if you enable it:

```
... [crit] 5408#9820: *19 CreateFile() "C:\nginx-1.17.8/html/Prüfstand.txt" failed (1113: No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /Pr%FCfstand.txt HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/"
```

With the MWE further down it is also not just a simple 404 but rather a 500.

That error hints towards an encoding issue. You'd use one of the methods of the [ngx_http_charset_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_charset_module.html) to fix it. You have included that in your edits. If you just define a `source_charset` and `charset` you will get an error saying `nginx: [emerg] no "charset_map" between the charsets "windows-1251" and "utf-8"` and the supplied win-utf mapping files don't include the mapping you need. It would encode FC as `FC  D18C ;   # small soft sign` ([ь](https://unicode-table.com/en/044C/)). What you'd need is a [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) map.

Now why do I assume there is a bug in autoindex and/or the windows nginx build? Well the following MWE based on the default config file for the nginx Windows build 1.17.8 does the conversion from d to ü and does rewrite the link to `http://localhost/Pr%FCfstan%C3%BC.txt` but won't touch the `%FC` though it will display as a ü. A side effect is that all ds are replaced with üs. As an example in word `Index`.

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    charset utf-8;
    source_charset windows-1251;
    charset_map  windows-1251  utf-8 {
        64  C3BC; # d -> ü
        FC  C3BC; # ü -> ü
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root html;
            autoindex on;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    }
}
```

At least in one case (can't find that link again) someone was successful by doing his [own build on Windows](http://nginx.org/en/docs/howto_build_on_win32.html). Alternatively you could use a e.g. a PHP script to generate the index in the way you want.

Comment: Thank you for that excellent answer and the work you've put into it. I find it really strange that the link generation of `d -> u` works, but `ü -> ü` does not. That's the actual bug, isn't it?

Comment: From what I can see that seems like a bug, yeha. I might be missing something as I haven't actually looked at the code. But form what I can see with what I've done this might be a bug.